# How to tar several files without containing their whole path in tar file

Tags: linux, bash, tar

Let's say I am in `/tmp`. I want to tar `/tmp/aaa/123`,`/tmp/bbb/222`.
The command I use is: `tar -vczf /tmp/my.tar.gz /tmp/aaa/123 /tmp/bbb/222`.
This command works fine.

However, when I use `tar -zxvf my.tar.gz`to decompress the tar file, it gives me 2 file(let's say I copied my.tar.gz to a path called pwd and now I am in pwd): pwd/tmp/aaa/123 and pwd/tmp/bbb/222. The result I expect is pwd/my/123 and pwd/my/222.

Are there any commands I can use to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make use of the --directory option.